# React-Moment gives: "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component"

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I've narrowed this down to find that the error occurs only when I try to pass the `<Moment />` component as described in the [React-Moment documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment). So far, I haven't found any explanations specific to this package and hope someone out there has had a similar issue!

The docs spell out a usage like this:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';

// then within the class component:
return (
        const dateToFormat = '1976-04-19T12:59-0500';
        <Moment>{dateToFormat}</Moment>
        );
```

And I'd like to take a raw date string like this:

`<Text>Created {this.props.postDate}</Text>`

which is stored thusly: `"postDate": "2019-01-31T04:13:31.224Z"`

but so far, anytime I add `<Moment>{this.props.postDate}</Moment>`, whether that be outside of or inside of the existing `<Text />` block I get red:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the documentation:

https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment#usage-with-react-native

```
<Moment element={Text}>{dateToFormat}</Moment>
```